# Поменять местами максимальный и минимальный элемент в двунаправленном списке

Tags: c++, список, односвязный-список

Имеется функция по нахождению минимального и максимального значения. Нужно поменять местами максимальный и минимальный элемент в двунаправленном списке через перенаправление связей.

```
  void Swap(Spis2 **b) {
    Spis2 *t = *b;
    Spis2 *max = *b;
    Spis2 *min = *b;
    int x;
    while (t->next != NULL) {
        if (t->next->info > max->info) {
            max = t->next;
            x = 0;
        }

        else if (t->next->info < min->info) {
            min = t->next;
            x = 1;
        }

        else
            t = t->next;
    }
    cout << "max = " << max->info << endl;
    cout << "min = " << min->info << endl;  
}
```

Comment: А вопрос-то в чём?

Comment: Где проблема?..

Comment: вопрос в самом задании, я не совсем понимаю как поменять местами эти элементы

Comment: @hope_op Насколько я понял, Вы нам предоставили лишь функции для замены элементов. А где заявленные функции по поиску минимального и максимального элементов?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

struct Node
{
  int data;
  Node* prev;
  Node* next;

  Node(int d) : data(d), prev(nullptr), next(nullptr) {};
};

class List
{
  private:
  Node* _beg;
  Node* _end;
  public:
  List() : _beg(nullptr), _end(nullptr) {};
  void push_back(int d);
  Node& max() const;
  Node& min() const;
  Node* begin() const {return _beg;};

  friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const List& list);
};

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const List& list)
{
  Node* cur = list.begin();

  while(cur != nullptr)
  {
      os << cur->data << " ";
      cur = cur->next;
  }

  return os;
}

void List::push_back(int d)
{
  Node* node = new Node(d);
  if(_beg == nullptr)
  {
    _beg = _end = node;
  }
  else
  {
    node->prev = _end;
    _end->next = node;
    _end = node;
  }
}

Node& List::max() const
{
  Node* beg = _beg;
  Node* next = _beg->next;
  Node* res = nullptr;

  while(next != nullptr)
  {
      if(beg->data < next->data)
      {
          res = next;
          beg = next;
      }

      next = next->next;
  }

  return *res;
}

Node& List::min() const
{
  Node* beg = _beg;
  Node* next = _beg->next;
  Node* res = nullptr;

  while(next != nullptr)
  {
      if(beg->data > next->data)
      {
          res = next;
          beg = next;
      }

      next = next->next;
  }

  return *res;
}

void swapNode(Node& max, Node& min)
{
  Node* tmpPrev = min.prev;
  Node* tmpNext = min.next;

  min.prev->next = &max;
  min.next->prev = &max;
  min.next = max.next;
  min.prev = max.prev;

  max.prev->next = &min;
  max.next->prev = &min;
  max.prev = tmpPrev;
  max.next = tmpNext;
}

int main()
{
  List list;
  list.push_back(3);
  list.push_back(9);
  list.push_back(1);
  list.push_back(2);
  list.push_back(4);
  list.push_back(100);
  list.push_back(2);
  list.push_back(5);

  Node& max = list.max();
  Node& min = list.min();

  std::cout << list << std::endl;

  swapNode(max, min);

  std::cout << list;

  return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Я делал так: брал не указатель на элемент а указатель на указатель на элемент.
Примерно вот так для однонаправленного:

```
void Swap(Spis2 **b) {
Spis2 *t = *b;
Spis2 **max = b;
Spis2 **min = b;
int x;
while (t->next != NULL) {
    if (t->next->info > (*max)->info) {
        max = &t->next;
        x = 0;
    }

    else if (t->next->info < (*min)->info) {
        min = &t->next;
        x = 1;
    }

    else
        t = t->next;
}
cout << "max = " << (*max)->info << endl;
cout << "min = " << (*min)->info << endl;

swap((*max)->next,(*min)->next);
swap((*max),(*min));
}
```

Для двунаправленного надо prev подправить.